# galaxy s3 browser screen width

Tags: html, mobile, amazon-s3, galaxy

Galaxy s3 has default browser and chrome. Both browsers alert width 964. 
How is it possible as specs says its width is 720?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.5;">-->
<title>Test mobile</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script>
function alertDimension()
{
    alert( "w: " + document.body.offsetWidth + ", h: " + document.body.offsetHeight );  
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="alertDimension();">
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Hello World
    </p>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it maybe do some scaling to be more compatible with desktop screen sizes? How about uncommenting that `<meta>`?

Comment: Try with `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Tested with meta scale uncommented:
default browser:
document.body.offsetWidth 344
window.innerWidth 360
chrome:
document.body.offsetWidth 344
window.innerWidth 360

Meta scale commented
default browser:
document.body.offsetWidth 964
window.innerWidth 980
chrome:
document.body.offsetWidth 964
window.innerWidth 360